# Sequence contains no elements Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My dbstructure is as follows

**StudentRegistrationTable**

```
Id      Name     
5       Sachin
```

**StudentReceiptTable**

```
Id      StudRegId     Fee    ST     Total      Status     DueDate 
1         5           873   127    1000         1        01/05/2016
2         5           873   127    2000         1        01/15/2016
3         5           873   127    3000         0        01/25/2016
4         5           873   127    4000         0        01/28/2016
5         5           873   127    5000         0        01/30/2016
```

Status indicates the payment mode.Status 1 indicates student has paid the receipt and 0 indicates the unpaid receipt

**Query**

```
  _dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r => (..condition))
                .Select(r => new RegistraionVM.RegDataTable
                 {    
                    ...
                    ...                      
                    NextDueAmount = r.StudentReceipts.
                                     Where(rc => rc.Status == false)
                                     .First().Total.ToString(),
                    NextDueDate = r.StudentReceipts.
                                    Where(rc => rc.Status == false)
                                    .First().DueDate.Date.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')                                     
                }).OrderByDescending(r => r.RegistrationID).ToList();
```

The above query returns the first unpaid amount and date(3000 & 01/25/2016).

The problem arises when student has paid all the receipt (ie status will be set to 1) and i am getting `Sequence contains no elements errror`.In that case I want to return  `FULL PAID` in both `NextDueAmount` and `NexDueDate`

**RegDataTable Class**

```
    public class RegDataTable
    {       
        ...
        ...     
        public string NextDueAmount { get; set; }
        public string NextDueDate { get; set; }           

    }
```

Comment: `.First()` will return that error if there are no items in the collection. Use `.FirstOrDefault();`, then check for `null`, then if not, access the properties

Comment: Thanks mate if you could post the answer I will accept it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `.First()` will throw the error is the collection of `StudentReceipt` returns no items (i.e. when the `Status` of all items is `true`). You need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and then check if the value is `null`, and if not then access the `Total` and `DueDate` properties.

This could make you controller code unnecessarily complex (and your also accessing the database twice to get the collection) so I suggest you use a view model (if its not already) with additional read only properties to return the results

```
public class RegDataTableVM
{
  ....
  public StudentReceipt Receipt { get; set; }
  public string NextDueAmount
  {
    get { return Receipt == null ? "FULL PAID" ? Receipt.Total.ToString() }
  }
  public string NextDueDate 
  {
    get { return Receipt == null ? "FULL PAID" ? Receipt.DueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") }
  }
```

and modify the query to

```
_dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
  .Where(r => (..condition))
  .Select(r => new RegDataTableVM
  {    
    ...
    ...
    Receipt = r.StudentReceipts.Where(rc => rc.Status == false).FirstOrDefault()                                     
  }).OrderByDescending(r => r.RegistrationID).ToList();
```

Side note: If your using `DisplayFor()` to generate the html, you can also make use of the `DisplayFormatAttribute`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", NullDisplayText = "FULL PAID"
public DateTime? NextDueDate
{
  get { return return Receipt == null ? null ? Receipt.DueDate }
}
```

Comment: If possible please look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961195/ajax-error-jquery-datatable)