# Ajax error - jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am using [jquery datatable](http://www.datatables.net) in my application.

When I am trying to bind the json response from the server I am getting the following message in the browser

`DataTables warning:table id=DataTables_Table_0-Ajax error.For more information about this error please seee http://datatables.net/tn/7`

and in the console of the browser as

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

When I dived deeped into the console i got the following exception `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CenterCode_16F8807C95C21FEFA99B4700E38D8ACB4A88C8E560B5640BD5E1FA148C99CCA5'.`And I dont know what this means??

Josn is returning successfully without any error?How can I solve this issue?

**JsonResult Function**

```
 public JsonResult GetDataTable(string finYear)
    {
        try
        {
            Common _cmn = new Common();
            List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> _dTableReg = new List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable>();


            _dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(r => _centerCodeIds.Contains(r.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.Id)
                                        && (r.TransactionDate.Value.Date >= _startFinDate && r.TransactionDate.Value.Date <= _endFinDate))
                            .Select(r => new RegistraionVM.RegDataTable
                            {
                                Centre = r.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.CentreCode,
                                CourseFee = r.TotalCourseFee.Value,
                                Discount = r.Discount.Value,
                                CurrEmpId = Int32.Parse(Session["LoggedUserId"].ToString()),
                                WalkInn = r.StudentWalkInn,
                                Receipt = r.StudentReceipts.Where(rc => rc.Status == false).FirstOrDefault(),
                                RegDate = r.TransactionDate,
                                RegistrationID = r.Id,
                                SalesPerson = r.StudentWalkInn.CROCount == (int)EnumClass.CROCount.ONE ?
                                                                        r.StudentWalkInn.Employee1.Name :
                                                                        r.StudentWalkInn.Employee1.Name + "," + r.StudentWalkInn.Employee2.Name,
                                StudentName = r.StudentWalkInn.CandidateName,
                                SoftwareUsed = string.Join(",", r.StudentRegistrationCourses
                                                     .SelectMany(c => c.MultiCourse.MultiCourseDetails
                                                     .Select(mc => mc.Course.Name))),
                                IsSalesIndividual = _currentRole == (int)EnumClass.Role.SALESINDIVIDUAL ? true : false

                            }).OrderByDescending(r => r.RegistrationID).ToList();    
        return Json(new { data = _dTableReg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**RegDataTable**

```
 public class RegDataTable
    {
        public int RegistrationID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RegDate { get; set; }
        public string Centre { get; set; }
        public string SalesPerson { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }              
        public int Discount { get; set; }
        public int CourseFee { get; set; }           
        public string SoftwareUsed { get; set; }
        public StudentReceipt Receipt { get; set; }
        public bool IsSalesIndividual { get; set; }
        public StudentWalkInn WalkInn { get; set; }
        public int CurrEmpId { get; set; }
        public int? NextDueAmount 
        {
            get { return Receipt == null ? 0 : Receipt.Total; }

        }
        public string NextDueDate 
        {
            get { return Receipt == null ? "" : Receipt.DueDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); }
        }

        public string MobileNo
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsSalesIndividual)
                {
                    if ((CurrEmpId == WalkInn.CRO1ID) || (CurrEmpId == WalkInn.CRO2ID))
                    {
                        return WalkInn.MobileNo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "-";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return WalkInn.MobileNo;
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

**html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dTable" data-url="@Url.Action("GetDataTable", "Registration")">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>RegDate</th>
                                    <th>Centre </th>
                                    <th>Sales Person </th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                    <th>Mobile</th>
                                    <th style="width:200px">S/W Used</th>
                                    <th>Discount</th>
                                    <th>CourseFee</th>
                                    <th>Next DueDetails</th>
                                    <th style="display:none">NextDueAmount</th>
                                    <th ></th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

**Calling DataTable from javascript**

```
 table = $(".dTable").dataTable({
        ...
        ...,

        columns: [
            { "data": "RegDate" },
            { "data": "Centre" },
            { "data": "SalesPerson" },
            { "data": "StudentName" },
            { "data": "MobileNo" },
            { "data": "SoftwareUsed" },
            { "data": "Discount" },
            { "data": "CourseFee" },
            { "data": "NextDueDate" },
            { "data": "NextDueAmount" },
            { "data": "RegistrationID" }

        ],

        //Defining checkbox in columns
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6)));
                    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                    return date.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + date.getFullYear()
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": [8],
                "bSortable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    if (row.NextDueAmount != 0) {                          
                        return data + ',' + row.NextDueAmount
                    }
                    else {
                        return "FULL PAID"
                    }
                }
            },
        ],

    });
```

**JsonResponse**
   [image]

Comment: add the server logs, what's the detailed exception?

Comment: The error means you have a model that has a property containing a model which in turn contains a property back to the original model. Most likely its a property in your `StudentWalkInn` or `StudentReceipt` thats causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should return Json(result). After you have built the list, you are only returning an empty data if exception thrown. Change your method result to:

```
return Json(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { error = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that piece of code.Now the question is updated please check it.I am not getting any error and json is returning successsfully

Comment: In that case simply return Json(_dTableReg);

Comment: What does the response look like when you check it with browser's dev tool?

Comment: Finally caught the error `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CenterCode_16F8807C95C21FEFA99B4700E38D8ACB4A88C8E560B5640BD5E1FA148C99CCA5'.`

Answer (score 0):

You *MUST add blank `<tbody>` tag in your table, like;

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

So that dataTable scripts can add data to tbody and initialize the table.

Answer (score 0):

for me i wasn't getting any thing in "data" of render which was causing the issue.So i used "full" rather than "data" and it worked for me.

Corrected :

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) 
{
    var date = new Date(parseInt(full.substr(6)));
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    return date.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + date.getFullYear()
}
```